# Razor: iterate items and sub items

Tags: razor, razorengine

I need to output something like:

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>Item1name
        <dd>subitem1name
        <dd>subitem2name
     <td>123</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>1230</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>Item2name
        <dd>subitem1name
     <td>1234</td>
     <td>10</td>
     <td>12340</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm using this template:

```
<tbody>
    @for(int i = 0; i < @Model.ItemsCount; i++) {
        <tr>
            <td>@(i+1)</td>
            <td>
            @Model.Items[i].Name;
            int j = 0;
            for(; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
                <dd>@(Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name)
            }
            </td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].CountStr</td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].CostStr</td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].TotalStr</td>
        </tr>
    }         
</tbody>
```

My classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public List<SubItem> Sub { get; set; } 
    public string CountStr { get; set;}
    public string CostStr {get; set; }
    public string TotalStr { get; set; }
    public int SubCount {get { return Sub.Count; }}
}
public class SubItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting exception when trying to parse. It says that `j` does not exist in the current context. I cannot figure out how to make it right.

Comment: Perhaps you could describe how it doesn't work? We have no idea what you've stored in your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `<dd/>` must be closed, not just `<dd>`. Code below works fine

```
<tbody>
        @for(int i = 0; i < @Model.ItemsCount; i++) {
            <tr>
                <td>@(i+1)</td>
                <td>@Model.Items[i].Name
                @for (int j = 0; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
                    <dd/>@Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name
                }
                </td>
                <td>@Model.Items[i].CountStr</td>
                <td>@Model.Items[i].CostStr</td>
                <td>@Model.Items[i].TotalStr</td>
            </tr>                
        }            
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, you are declaring the variable `j` outside the subitem `for` loop:

```
int j = 0;
for(; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
    <dd>@(Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name)
}
```

The loop should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
    <dd>@(Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name)
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use your code. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is with the lines:

```
int j = 0;
for(; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
```

These lines are not interpreted as Razor, but as raw text. This results in the variable `j` not being declared or defined on the line:

```
<dd>@(Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name)
```

The reason is that you need to be in a code context to be able to write C# code. You do that by using the `@` sign, but that only interprets a single expression as code. It doesn't switch to a code context. So you can't use the @ sign if you want to write multiple lines of code. If you want to do that, you need to enter a code context by using braces, prepended by an @ sign: `@{ }`.

Try this instead:

```
<tbody>
    @for(int i = 0; i < @Model.ItemsCount; i++) {
        <tr>
            <td>@(i+1)</td>
            <td>
            @Model.Items[i].Name
            @{
                int j = 0;
                for(; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
                    <dd>@(Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name)
                }
            }
            </td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].CountStr</td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].CostStr</td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].TotalStr</td>
        </tr>
    }         
</tbody>
```

Alternatively, you can declare and initialize the `j` variable in the `for` loop, and tell the Razor compiler that the `for` loop is code, by prepending it with an `@` sign. Like this:

```
<tbody>
    @for(int i = 0; i < @Model.ItemsCount; i++) {
        <tr>
            <td>@(i+1)</td>
            <td>
            @Model.Items[i].Name
            @for(int j = 0; j < Model.Items[i].SubCount; j++) {
                <dd>@(Model.Items[i].Sub[j].Name)
            }
            </td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].CountStr</td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].CostStr</td>
            <td>@Model.Items[i].TotalStr</td>
        </tr>
    }         
</tbody>
```

I would recommend you to follow the last example.

You can check out [Phil Haack's Razor quick reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/) for some examples of how the Razor syntax works.

And by the way, it's invalid HTML to have an `<dd>` tag if it's outside a `<dt>` list. So you might want to reconsider your HTML structure. You can read the documentation on the `<dd>` tag on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dd).